# How to prevent subequation numbers from appearing on all slidews with \onslide?

Tags: beamer, animations, subequations

I am trying to present two subequations on two slides with \onslide as given in the MWE. How do I prevent from showing '(1b)' on the Slide 2? I want it to be partly visible on Slide 1 and fully visible on Slide 2.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{eqnarray}
        % \centering
        \onslide<1-> {y = mx + ac - bc} \\
        \onslide<2-> {y = mx + c(a - b)}
    \end{eqnarray}
    \label{eq:oi}
\end{subequations}
\end{frame}%

\end{document}
```

**Slide 1**

[image]

**Slide 2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is explained at the end of section 23.4 of `beamer`'s manual.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:oi}
\begin{align}
y &= mx + ac - bc \\
\uncover<2->{y &= mx + c(a - b)\\}
\notag
\end{align}
\vspace{-2ex}
\end{subequations}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]